Logging for DefaultAzureCredential in Visual Studio
I am trying to get logging working for the DefaultAzureCredential in Visual Studio. I setup up the logging but when I get a DefaultAzureCredential token no logging in outputed in Visual Studio console.
Here is my program.cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
     builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
     builder.Logging.AddConsole();

     // Add services to the container.
     builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

     var app = builder.Build();

     // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
         // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
         app.UseHsts();
     }


     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "default",
         pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

     app.Run();
 }

Here is how I am getting the token
     DefaultAzureCredentialOptions options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
  {
      Diagnostics =
      {
          LoggedHeaderNames = { "x-ms-request-id" },
          LoggedQueryParameters = { "api-version" },
          IsLoggingContentEnabled = true,
          IsLoggingEnabled = true,
          IsAccountIdentifierLoggingEnabled = true
      },
      ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true
  };

  var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(options); 
  
  AccessToken token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));

Any suggestions on why this isn't working?

First a note about the use of
builder.Services.AddAzureClientsCore(true);

as suggested by several other answers.
This method can be a bit of a trap. It will not work by itself, but:

Note that even when setting to true, you'll need to either inject the
AzureEventSourceLogForwarder somewhere in your app or retrieve it from
the service collection.

I was able to extract this crucial bit of information from the dll metadata in Visual Studio.
In fact, Microsoft wants you to not use this method.
The correct solution for your scenario is described here.
Applied to your code, it would look like this.
I had to put the code in pastebin due to this. Sorry for the inconvenience.


I setup up the logging but when I get a DefaultAzureCredential token no logging in outputed in Visual Studio console.

Thanks @Jesse for pointing out to the correction, updating my solution as per your proposed approach.
Firstly, check you have added the necessary NuGet package for logging. Use the Microsoft.Extensions.Azure package for logging to the console.

Then, in the Program.cs file, Integrate the AzureEventSourceLogForwarder from the Microsoft.Extensions.Azure package to capture and forward Azure SDK logs to the ASP.NET logging infrastructure.

Code:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

// Configure logging
builder.Logging.AddConsole(); // Add logging to the console

// Set logging level for Azure.Identity namespace
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug); // or LogLevel.Information

// Add Azure SDK logs forwarding
builder.Services.AddAzureClientsCore(true); // Implicitly starts the forwarder

// Configure Application Insights telemetry.
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseAzureEventSourceLogForwarder(); // Add Azure SDK logs forwarding to ILogger

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

app.Run();
]


I added the nuget package and configured the logging level and I am still not getting any credential logging to the Visual Studio output window.

Check that you're using a version of the Azure.Identity package that supports logging.

This is incorrect; the Azure SDK packages, including Azure.Identity emit logs to ETW.  Setting up logging the way that you have does not capture SDK logs for Identity.

I have modified the above code by this Azure SDK logs emitted to ETW will be captured by the AzureEventSourceLogForwarder and forwarded to the ASP.NET logging infrastructure

So, you went back and edited your answer to blatantly copy the content and code from my answer below, but left the screen shots showing the wrong log information.

Thanks, @JesseSquire for pointing out to the correction, updating my solution as per your proposed approach. It might be helpful anyway community get benefits from the solution.

The solution that already existed in another answer that you coped over after the fact?

I apologize for any confusion my earlier answer may have caused. Your input is invaluable, and I'm grateful for your contribution. I've updated the solution accordingly to reflect the accurate approach.

The Azure SDK packages emit logs to ETW.  You've hooked up the AzureEventSourceListener, which will capture them, but you're not writing those captured logs anywhere.  For example, to emit them to the console, you'd need to create a console logger:
using AzureEventSourceListener listener = 
    AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();

To integrate with ILogger and the ASP.NET logging infrastructure, the easiest way is to use the AzureEventSourceLogForwarder from the Microsoft.Extensions.Azure package, which implicitly starts a listener and writes the captured logs to ILogger for you.
That would look something like the following, in which AddAzureClientsCore creates and starts the forwarder on your behalf.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAzureClientsCore(true);

More discussion and examples can be found in Logging with the Azure SDK for .NET.
